# Execution Requirements for Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm analyzing the following code.  My question is: for the setTimeout() function, how is it being called?  It looks to me like it's just being assigned to the variable this.timer, and that it has not yet been called.  But the function is executed nonetheless.  What am I missing / not understanding?  Thank you so much for your help in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var validateUsername = $('#validateUsername');
$('#username').keyup(function () {
var t = this; 
if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
  if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
  validateUsername.removeClass('error').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"      height="16" width="16" /> checking availability...');

  this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax-validation.php',
      data: 'action=check_username&username=' + t.value,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      success: function (j) {
        validateUsername.html(j.msg);
      }
    });
  }, 200);

  this.lastValue = this.value;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> how is it being called?

The function name (`setTimeout`) is followed by a `(` character, then some arguments, then a `)` character.

The first of those arguments is a function expression that is split across multiple lines.

> It looks to me like it's just being assigned to the variable this.timer

Its return value (an identifier that can be used with `clearTimeout`) is being assigned, not the `setTimeout` function itself.

Comment: Oh ok.  So to follow up on that, if I were to write a line of code such as: var a = function() {}, would a() execute or would it simply be defined?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you just assign a function expression to a variable, and do nothing else, then it wouldn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

> Executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.

`setTimeout` trigger the given function parameter(first parameter) after amount of miliseconds parameter(second parameter).

the return value is:

> timeoutID is the numerical ID of the timeout, which can be used later with window.clearTimeout.

[**Make sure to real all the MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

The function is called here:

```
this.timer = setTimeout(function() {...});
```

`setTimout()` executes the anonymous function after the delay and meanwhile returns its numerical ID. `this.timer` then stores that ID, which can be later with `clearTimeout`.